# Как объединить два списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

есть задача: нужно объединить два списка:

```
a = [3,4,1,2]
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

на выходе нужно получить:

```
c = [3,4,1,2,5,6]
```

Нужно не нарушать порядок элементов списка, добавить только недостающие элементы в конец. Нашел только решение в библиотеке NumPy, но она мне не подходит, т.к. нужно загрузить решение задачи на сайт с автоматической системой тестов.

Comment: Метки python-2.x и python-3.x вместе имеет смысл ставить только если вам нужно, чтобы код работал и на Python 2, и на Python 3. Вы уверены что поддержка Python 2 вам нужна?

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить такое очевидное решение через `list comprehenshion`:

```
a = [3,4,1,2]
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

c = a + [x for x in b if x not in a]
print(c) # [3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Из первого массива сделайте set.

Если порядок недостающих элементов тоже важен, то пройдите по второму с проверкой - если текущего элемента нет в set - добавьте его к первому массиву

Answer (score 1):

Можно сходу придумать кучу способов с разной степенью ручного вмешательства. Наиболее "автоматический" наверное будет такой:

```
c = list(dict.fromkeys(a + b))
```

Но работает данный способ только начиная с какой-то версии питона, когда сортировка элементов в словарях стала *устойчивой*. В более ранних версиях порядок элементов может нарушиться.

А типовой "ручной" способ - с помощью **спискового сокращения** выбрать те элементы второго списка, которых нет в первом, и добавить получившийся список к первому списку.

Comment: на примере a = [1,2,5,4] и b = [3,4,1,2,5,6] ваше решение выдает c = [1,2,5,4,3,6], а нужен список c = [3,1,2,5,4,6]

Comment: мне важно сохранить порядок

Comment: @ch1ba объясните, что вы понимаете под порядком в данном случае?

Comment: @ch1ba это что за такой порядок интересный? Вы же сами написали, что добавлять в конец недостающие элементы..

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain

c = list(chain(a, filter(lambda item: item not in a, b)))
print(c) # -> [3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6]
```

Comment: на примере a = [1,2,5,4] и b = [3,4,1,2,5,6] ваше решение выдает c = [1,2,5,4,3,6], а нужен список c = [3,1,2,5,4,6]

Comment: @ch1ba, добавьте это в вопрос. И постарайтесь как-то описать логику получения результирующего списка.